# Magento printout pdf editing style and layout

Tags: magento-1.9, pdf

Our pdf invoice printout table columns are not aligning properly and I don't know how to fix it

A bit I would like to edit the style also to get rid on the dark gray
For example Where is this?
`Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Items_Invoice_Default`

[image]

Update2

I managed to change the header color to white
But the alignment still remains
I went to `mage/sales/model/order/pdf/items/invoice/default.pdf`
And I edited the alignments, It did changed the pdf, but it gave so unexpected results that it still looks the same :(

Comment: Hi try this in you file 'align' => 'left',

Comment: Thanks!
I went to mage/sales/model/order/pdf/items/invoice/default.pdf
and edited  like for an hour  - trying  'align' => 'left' /right/left/center
and I did see changes in the pdf, but I don't understand the logic at all. When I put it to right, then it is to the right, when on left, then it is more to the right and to the center is also to the right
wtf? It is driving me crazy.

I managed to change the header color though finally

Comment: I tried using width and negative values like
  'width' => -35
and it helped me somewhat, but I bet not OK solution at all

Comment: In the end we just took a plugin to do this, cause our client wanted to change a lot of the colors and other decor.